# Extending File-system after EBS volume increase on M5 type EC2 with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

**Production AWS Instance:** We have an m5 ec2 nitro instance that is in need of query optimization. However, we are in a time crunch and have decided to temporarily throw memory and storage at this until we can complete the optimization of queries. (Apologies in advance)

There is **50GB** on one **EBS volume** **(/dev/sda1)** and another **50GB** **on a second volume (/dev/sdf)**. As far as I can tell, the EC2 is only using one of the 50GB volumes, **dev/sda1**.

**Linux Kernal version: 4.4.0-1128-aws**
**32GB RAM** (M5a.2xlarge)

Our **/dev/nvme0n1p1 | (/tmp)** directory is filling up creating an SQL 28 No Disk Space error and we want to increase the size of the **/tmp** directory from **20GB to 50GB.** while we optimize queries to reduce the sizes of the temporary database (.MAI) files stored in /tmp

**Where I am at:** In our testing environment/EC2 (also an M5.2xlarge) I was able to increase the volume size to **100GB** and I have followed the steps in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

- **This is what shows when I run** **lsblk**

```
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

nvme0n1             259:0    0   100G  0 disk                                                                                                         
├─nvme0n1p1         259:1    0    20G  0 part /                                                                                                       
├─nvme0n1p2         259:2    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]                                                                                                  
└─nvme0n1p3         259:3    0    28G  0 part                                                                                                         
  ├─vg_xxx-logs     251:0    0     8G  0 lvm  /var/log                                                                                                
  └─vg_xxx-app      251:1    0    19G  0 lvm  /home/xxx
```

**This is what shows when I run df -hT:**

```
Filesystem              Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                    devtmpfs   16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.1G  183M  3.0G   6% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1          ext4       20G  8.6G   11G  45% /
tmpfs                   tmpfs      16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                   tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   tmpfs      16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0              squashfs   44M   44M     0 100% /snap/certbot/1788
/dev/loop1              squashfs  111M  111M     0 100% /snap/core/12834
/dev/loop3              squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1434
/dev/loop5              squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2409
/dev/loop4              squashfs   25M   25M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/4046
/dev/loop2              squashfs   56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/mapper/vg_xxx-logs xfs       8.0G  362M  7.7G   5% /var/log
/dev/loop6              squashfs   26M   26M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/5656
/dev/loop8              squashfs   44M   44M     0 100% /snap/certbot/2035
/dev/loop7              squashfs   62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/mapper/vg_xxx-app  xfs        19G  4.7G   15G  25% /home/xxx
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                   tmpfs     3.1G     0  3.1G   0% /run/user/1001
```

As you can see, it shows that **nvme0n1** has **100GB** available, however, the 3 partitions still equal **50GB**. when I get to step 7 on the AWS documentation on extending the filesystem to occupy the new added volume space, I get the following:

```
ubuntu@ip-xx-xx-xx-xxx:~$ **sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1**                                                                                           
resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)                                                                                                                   
**The filesystem is already 5242619 (4k) blocks long.  Nothing to do!**
```

I have an ext4 filesystem (except that I see two lvms in the sub directory of **nvme0n1p3** but I don’t think that changes anything) and have tried **growpart**, **parted**, but these solutions found online are generally for Ubuntu and not specifically for EC2 EBS volumes, so I do not want to divert too much away from what should be a AWS provided solution that I cannot seem to find. That being said, those also produced error messages saying the drive/directory was in use.

My understanding is that AWS EBS allows for an ec2 to increase volume size and then extend the file-system without stopping the instance or unmounting the device being extended. Nonetheless, I have not been able to do the same when stopping the staging instance I am testing on. I am open to stopping the instance to get this done, however, would prefer to do it without unmounting device and/or stopping instance.

I can also upgrade the instance to provide more RAM if need be, but I’d still need to extend the filesystem first.

### Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you must grow your partition first before you can grow your filesystem. EBS is just a normal disk and nothing special or different.

Comment: Thank you, It wont let me grow the 1st partition, only the 3rd one. Do I need to move the 2nd and 3rd partitions first? Or does EBS handle all of that even if you select a partition that is adjacent to another one or more?

Answer (score 0):

Extending a Linux file system after resizing a volume:

1. login to instance;
2. Type `df -h` to list the info about the file system;
3. Type `lsblk`;
4. Check your volume name;
5. To extend the partition on the root volume, use the following `growpart` command.

   Notice that there is a space between the device name and the partition number.

   ```bash
   growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1

   # (1 = number of partitions)
   ```
6. Check the size again with `df -h` and `lsblk`
7. After extending the partition, extend the whole filesystem `resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1`

Comment: So I am able to get it to work when I use it on the last partition (/dev/nvme0n1 3) and that partition will grow, however, it will not work when I type the command to resize the first partition (/dev/nvme0n 1). I have seen examples of using GUI programs that can accomplish this, but I need to know how to expand the first partition to allow for the resize to take effect and that would entail moving the 2nd and third partitions, correct?